# Is it possible to add tab-like functionality to tmux panes?

Tags: tmux

I generally use tmux with 3-4 panes open. One of these panes is rarely used, so I'd be happy to hide it away somewhere. I suppose I could do this in a new window, but I'd rather hide it "behind" an existing pane.

For example, I'd like to keep `rails server` running in the background because I rarely need to refer to it, so `guard` occupies that pane instead. When I need to look at the `rails server` output, I'll switch to the `guard` pane and then "tab" over to the `rails server`.

At least, that's the ideal situation, but I can't figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: What is the objection to having a new window, which exactly describes what you want as long as you substitute "pane" for "tab" and "window" for "pane" in your description?

Comment: @chepner I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Tmux's panes are very different from tabs as we know them from applications like browsers. Windows are more like tabs, but basically I'd like to house multiple windows inside a single pane, and be able to switch between them. Or at least something that gives me that sort of functionality. Sadly it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: It's all just interface differences. In the end, it's just a way of logically grouping related terminals into one physical terminal.

Comment: Sure, and I'd like to find a way to logically group related terminals into one tmux pane, if possible.

Comment: It's not (unless you run a nested `tmux` as the command inside a pane). I really think you just want a separate window for `rails server`. If you want to keep the resulting group of windows separate from other windows, you can always start a new session to hold those windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tmux currently does not provide the functionality of 'hiding' panes.

For now, the closest tmux comes to hiding panes is the 'pane zoom' functionality. It is toggled with `prefix + z`. When 'on', the pane is resized to 100% of the window and all the other panes are hidden. Setting the pane zoom to 'off' unhides the hidden panes.

That said, I think the 'zoom' functionality is not ideal for your use case. Other have pointed it out: just using a new window that doesn't get in your way might do the trick and is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `break-pane` and `join-pane` - see [this question on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145857/32950).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what is in your mind of the concept "tab"; however, from what you want, a window is more than enough.

Imagine you have a "tab" in tmux, then, you more or less have to switch to that tab in order to see the output, so, the operation is exactly the same with window of tmux.

Normally, I type `<c-x> c` to have a new window, and then go back to the main workspace (the previous window) with `<c-x> p` and open my vim there to work. I might have multiple panes on my main workspace with tmux pane (not with vim pane, cos i need to have the terminal always to navigate). Then after I change things, save, just type another `<c-x> p` to go to the server and see what happen there

(note that I bind `<c-b>` to `<c-x>`)